# Menu retrátil que não se fecha

Tags: html, css, menu

Tenho um menu retrátil, mas só consigo fazê-lo abrir, mas não fechar.

Preciso que ele feche ao clicar em qualquer lugar da tela fora do menu.

Conheço html e css. o Javascript estou tendo contato com ele agora então não sei bem dizer nada sobre.

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>
        <div class="backg"></div>
        <nav class="menu" id="principal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" class="voltar">Voltar</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Fórum</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cursos <span>+</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contato <span>+</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            header {
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: #5b8594;
                position: fixed;    
            }

            .menu-icon{
                position: fixed;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color:  #5b8594;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: all .4s;
                left: 300px;
                top: 0;
            }

            .menu-icon:hover{
                background-color:  #fff;
                color: #5b8594;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: all .4s;
                left: 300px;
                top: 0;
            }

            #check {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            .menu {
                height: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                background-color: #222;
                top:0;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition: all .2s;
            }

            #principal {
                width: 300px; 
                left: -300px;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            ul li a{
                display: block;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-family: 'Arial';
                padding: 10px;
                border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
                color: #ccc;
                text-decoration: none;
                transition: all 0.2s;
            }

            ul li span{
                float: right;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }

            ul li a:hover{
                background-color: #5b8594;

            }

            .voltar{
                margin-top: 60px;
                background-color: #111;
                border-left: solid 5px #444;

            }

            .backg {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                top:0;
                position: fixed;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
                display: none;
            }

            #check:checked ~.backg{
                display: block;
            }

            #check:checked ~ #principal{
                transform: translateX(300px);
            }
```

Comment: Tem o JS para colocar aqui também? Assim alguém poderia testar com o Snippet.

Comment: Então, não usei JS, tem alguma forma de fazer sem?

Comment: Gostaria de uma solução usando JS ou jQuery?

Comment: Seria em jQuery mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Para esse tipo de menu você consegue apenas com CSS, com a pseudo-classe:focus, pois ele aplica ao elemento quando é clicado, e quando clicamos fora ou em outro elemento, ele perde o estado de foco, retirando assim o estilo aplicado. Exemplo:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.popup-menu {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}
.bt-menu:focus + .popup-menu {
  display: block;
}
.popup-menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.popup-menu a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.popup-menu a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="bt-menu">Menu</button>
<ul class="popup-menu">
  <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Entendi, estou testando aqui agora e bem isto mesmo que eu preciso,estou tentando montar no meu código desta forma que me mostrou pra ver.

Este tipo de função só funciona com botão ou qualquer elemento clicável funciona?

Comment: Qualquer elemento que suporte a pseudo-classe ":focus". Geralmente os clicáveis como botões, links, inputs, etc.

Comment: Diego, consegui fazer funcionar em parte.

Quando o menu aparece, dentre dele teria um menu accordion, mas assim que clico em um dos botões para expandir lá dentro as opções, ele perde o `focus` e  fecha o popup-menu.